# mysql and memory problems in ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: server, mysql, ram

I set up a VPS on Amazon some days ago. I installed LAMP server and then uploaded some sites there. Everything was working fine until yesterday I noticed the sites showing database connection errors. I checked the error log  in /var/log/mysql/ and it seems that there are some memory problems. You can see the last records from the error log here:
https://paste.ubuntu.com/23533774/

I read somewhere that "Cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool" indicates that this is memory problem and a solution to it would be adding a swap file.

What I wanted to know is if I should increase memory ram for the VPS or if I should add this swap file. Or perhaps there's another solution I don't know about.

Additional info:
 - Memory Ram available now is 1GB
 - There's about 2 html sites, 2 wordpress sites, 1 joomla site and 3 other php sites. Possible couple more sites to be added.
 - This is the first time I set up a server

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284532/amazon-ec2-mysql-aborting-start-because-innodb-mmap-x-bytes-failed-errno-12 you need to add a swap page.

You can follow this to setup the swap page:

http://www.prowebdev.us/2012/05/amazon-ec2-linux-micro-swap-space.html

According to this site (I'm just copying here)

Steps below show how to make a swap space for your Micro instance. I assume you have AWS Account with a Micro instance running.

1. Run `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=1024`
2. Run `mkswap /swapfile`
3. Run `swapon /swapfile`
4. Add this line `/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0` to `/etc/fstab`

Step 4 is needed if you would like to automatically enable swap file after each reboot.

Some useful command related to SWAP space:

```
$ swapon -s   
$ free -k

$ swapoff -a
$ swapon  -a
```

References:

1. http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/how-to-add-swap-space/
2. http://cloudstory.in/2012/02/getting-the-best-out-of-amazon-ec2-micro-instances/
3. http://cloudstory.in/2012/02/adding-swap-space-to-amazon-ec2-linux-micro-instance-to-increase-the-performance/
4. http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: I assume the best option is to add the swap file then.
I did as you mentioned and things are working fine again.
Thanks for the help.